# A question on algorithm complexity

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, recursive-algorithms

It is well-known that the evaluating the Discrete Fourier Transform definition directly has a complexity $O(N^{2})$
for a signal with bandwidth $N$. How to see or show that the fast
Fourier transform has a complexity $O(p\log p)$? since it would also
involve solving module equations involving $p$ and $N$?

Thanks for any helpful answers.